# E-mail notifications on filtered questions

Tags: feature-request, notifications, feed

In the ideal world, I would like to receive notifications (RSS or e-mail) about popular (above X views) or highly rated (above X votes) questions on SO with specific tags.

It would be a great way to educate yourself in specific theme, filtering out not so popular topics.

Example:
Receive notification for new questions tagged "Magento" with 1000+ views or rated 5+.

Questions:

- Is there any such functionality in SO?
- Are there any third-party tools to achieve this?
- Is there an API to build such a tool?

Comment: You can receive notifications about tags you select. To define it, go to http://stackexchange.com/users/184369/jevgeni-bogatyrjov?tab=subscriptions However, the filtering you suggest I think it is not implemented.

Comment: I thought that creating Google Alert for something like [magento+"1k+views"+site:stackoverflow.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=magento+"1k+views"+site:stackoverflow.com) or
[magento+"popular+question"+site:stackoverflow.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=magento+"popular+question"+site:stackoverflow.com) might work, but it seems that those searches return many question lists and almost no questions.